# Keras VGG16 - model.save and load giving different result

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to load a saved model in order to use it for predictions after I restart the kernel. While saving the model seems to work, loading does not seem to work without issues. Heres what I have done:

I have retrained a VGG16 model using Keras:

```
vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers[:-1]:
    model.add(layer)


model.layers.pop()
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.add(Dense(26, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(Adam(lr=.0000025), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Next I have trained the model:

```
    model.fit_generator(train_batches,validation_data=validation_batches, 
epochs=85, verbose=1,callbacks=[tbCallBack,earlystopCallback])
```

and finally I am saving my model like so:

```
model.save("model.h5")
```

Now when I restart the kernel and load the model again using:

```
from keras.models import load_model

new_model = load_model("model.h5")
```

While the model does load, I get a warning telling me:

> C:\Users...\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py:291:
>   UserWarning: Error in loading the saved optimizer state. As a result,
>   your model is starting with a freshly initialized optimizer.
>   warnings.warn('Error in loading the saved optimizer '

Furthermore, when I use the loaded model for predictions, I get wrong values (very different values from the one I trained) and it appears that the model has not been trained at all. However, when I check .get_weights I see that weights have been loaded.

I have also tried to save and load the model via json and weights only like so:

```
# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("model_weights.h5")
```

and loading:

```
#load json and create model
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
load_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
load_model.load_weights("model_weights.h5")
```

While loading the model this way does not throw me an error message, I still get predictions much worse than my previously trained model. In order to ensure that the model loading works I did the following:

- I checked the weights of the trained model and the loaded model and they appear to be the same.
- Also checking the models summary "model.summary()" displays the same architecture.

So to my understanding, having the same architecture and the same weights should yield the same model i.e. results - but I can't figure out why this is not the case

What baffles me even further is that when I use model.get_weights() and model.set_weights() it works perfectly, e.g.:

```
#getting weights from the old model
weights = model.get_weights()

# setting weights of the new model
new_model.set_weights(weights)
```

Comment: You mentioned that you got bad predictions. This may not be the best measure. Also it's not clear whether you got good predictions before saving the model. Have you compared the weights between before and after?

Comment: @de1 With bad predictions I mean that the model's performance regarding its predicting performance is much worse than the trained model I saved earlier. It's such a drastic drop in performance that I would consider the model to be untrained. Also when I try to continue the training, I see that the model's loss starts off much higher than it ended before. As you suggested I checked the model weights and I see that the saved and loaded model appear to have the same weights (updated my post). Hence I assume the error is related to the way I build/retrain the model, but I am not sure where to look